# iMessage and facetime not displaying my number

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, facetime

I have an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.2, I recently turned off the iMessage and FaceTime and then ejected my SIM card and inserted SIM card of another network. After few hours I again switched my SIM again to previous network.

After that I am trying to activate my iMessage and FaceTime but no luck. It is not displaying my number in address.
I checked my number in Phone but there my number is correct.

I have tried network reset, phone reset, hard reset, turning  on and off both services but no luck. How do I go back to using FaceTime and iMessage on my original network?

Answer (score 2):

Ring your carrier.

They may have to reset your phone's profile, if the other SIM messed it up.  They can send the new data (connection profile) remotely, you just OK it when it arrives.

My carrier sometimes sends me a new phone profile after a major iOS update, or if they add new functionality etc. I can easily imagine swapping SIM cards could mess up the original profile.